# Prove an integral inequation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Prove that if a function is descending on [0; 1], then
$\forall\theta\in(0;1)\quad \theta\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx \leq \int\limits_0^\theta f(x)dx$.

If a see $\leq$, then there is an idea to use limits. I've tried to play with integral sums but all I've got is that $\int\limits_0^\theta f(x)dx \gt f(\theta)\theta$ (but it's obvious without integral sums).

Comment: What you have done. Any  or ideas, please try to 

Comment: I note that the inequality is an equality for $\theta \in \{0,1\}$.  Have you picked a decreasing $f$ and sketched an example (graphs of the left side and right side of the inequality versus $\theta$) to perhaps get some insight into what is going on?

Comment: Maybe the intermediate value theorem is helpful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Let $g(y):= \int_0^y f(x) dx$. Then $g(y)$ is concave down.

Apply Jensen's inequality with $x_1=0, x_2=1$ and $t=\theta$.

**Added** Let $0 < \theta <1$.

Then
$$
g(\theta)-g(0)=\int_{0}^\theta f(x)dx \geq \theta f(\theta) \\
g(1)-g(\theta)=\int_\theta^1f(x)dx \leq (1-\theta)f(\theta)
$$
Multiplying the first ineqaulity by $(1-\theta)$ and the second by $\theta$ gives your inequality.

If you replace $0,1$ by $x_0,x_1$ and $\theta$ by $t$ you get the Jensen inequality for $g$ under the assumption that $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: It seems I'm not very smart. How to prove g(y) is concave down? It has some sense: f is descending, so our plot is going up slower and slower, but how to prove it without derivative?

Comment: @Maxim A differentiable function is concave down if and only if its derivative is decreasing. And the Fundamental Theorem of Caculus tells you exactly what $g'$ is.

Comment: g might not be differentiable, might it?

Comment: @Maxim You do not need $g$ to be differentiable, knowing that you integrate a decreasing function suffices. See the edit.

Comment: Wow, it's brilliant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without assuming that $f$ is differentiable, we can show that $F:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ where $F(\theta) =\int_0^\theta f(x) \, dx$ is concave.

Assuming that $f$ is bounded we have that $F$ is continuous. Since $f$ is nonincreasing we have for $\theta_1 < \theta_2$

$$F(\theta_2) - F\left(\frac{\theta_1 + \theta_2}{2}\right) \leqslant F\left(\frac{\theta_1 + \theta_2}{2}\right) - F(\theta_1)$$

Hence,

$$F\left(\frac{\theta_1 + \theta_2}{2}\right) \geqslant \frac{1}{2} ( F(\theta_1) + F(\theta_2))$$

Since $F$ is continuous and midpoint concave it must be concave and for all $\theta \in (0,1)$,

$$\frac{F(\theta)}{\theta} =\frac{F(\theta)-F(0)}{\theta-0}\geqslant \frac{F(1)-F(0)}{1-0} = F(1)$$

Thus,

$$\frac{1}{\theta}\int_0^\theta f(x) \, dx \geqslant \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$$

Comment: Thank you, I got it. But I didn't know the fact "Since F is continuous and midpoint...", so I think the problem author doesn't suppose a reader to know it. May be there is another solution? Anyway, your answer is good, I learnt a new theorem.